# why OHC cache not released replaced values?

Tags: java

my code is:

```
       OHCache<Integer, String> cache = OHCacheBuilder.<Integer, String>newBuilder()
                .keySerializer(new IntSerializer())
                .valueSerializer(new StringSerializer())
                .capacity(64 * 1024 * 1024)
                .eviction(Eviction.LRU)
                .throwOOME(true)
                .build();
        byte[] _1mb = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            // cache.remove(1)
            cache.put(1, new String(_1mb));
        }
```

Direct Memory will always increase more than 64M. actually, in my prod. It increased 200G.
If I open line 'remove(1)'. It will work under 64M.
Can someone help me?

work under capacity.
release memory  hold by  replaced old values.
https://github.com/snazy/ohc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.